# Dart or Flutter how to read a binary file encoded by float32 little endian and convert it into List<double>?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using file.readAsBytes(). but It only provides List to receive data. And I'm trying Uint8List but isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readAsBytes` is going to give you a list of bytes. It will likely be a `Uint8List` or maybe just a `List<int>`. (If it isn't a `Uint8List`, convert it by using `Uint8List.fromList(anotherByteArray)`.)

Then use: `ulist.buffer.asFloat32List()`